# Is Passed Argument the Element or the Event?

Tags: events, dom, this, getelementbyid

In the script below, is eORe the element or the event?

```
$("#elementid").click(function(eORe) {
   eORe.innerHTML += ' is the object of attention';
   eORe.stopPropagation(); // don't bubble up
});
```

Note: One of the commands in the function must be wrong, based on the question.

Comment: I'd point out that either way, collectively that function doesn't make sense because you're treating it like both simultaneously. For the record though, ``eORe`` is the event object.